# Photos too large in div

Tags: html, css, photo

I am fairly new to html/css and I am coding a website for my mom. (Live example here: http://jleblanc.pancakeapps.com/index.html) and for the life of me I can't make the photos any smaller. Do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: in the <img> tag, you have height and width attributes that you can set.

Comment: Which photos are you talking about? The background images?

Comment: yes. the ones that can parallax

Comment: The best approach would be to resize the images in photoshop to the size you want. Has the awesome benefit of reducing file size too.

Comment: His images are not large at all, it's more a css scaling issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about the oversize background images in your colored tabs, the problem is that you have `background-size: contain` set which is scaling the image to the container size.  Choose another background size (`background-size: (x)% (y)%` maybe?

(You'll get better answers if you reduce your question down to the specifics of what you're trying to do and give example code of what's not working, rather than just linking to a website and asking what's wrong with it)

Comment: You'll have to play around with the sizes (and probably with the aspect ratio of your images) to find one that suits your parallax without tiling.

Answer (score 1):

If images are set in following format:

```
<div id="PlaceHolder"><img src="source.jpg"/></div>
```

You can add rule in CSS:

```
#PlaceHolder img{
width: 400px;
}
```

If you set height or width - it will automatically resize image maintaining it's aspect ratio.

Comment: The images in this question are `background-image` so I don't think this answer applies to the question

Comment: Yeah I realized that only after since OP didn't specify if it's background or just images.

Answer (score 0):

You can set image as responsive by making them size to 100% so they can fit any size.thanks